# Best Way to Convert All Attributes On Java Object With Empty Strings to Null

Tags: java, spring, performance, reflection, getter-setter

I've been searching around but haven't been able to find a good example of this. I have a POJO such as

```
public class SomeObject implements Serializable {
   private String name;
   private String residence;
   private String phone;

   // standard getters and setters
}
```

I am trying to find a better, more dynamic way using reflection to find if any of those attributes contain empty strings e.g. "", and set those attributes to **null**. I know I could manually loop through the object and look at each attribute individually and set it that way, but I figure there has to be a better programmatic solution than that. Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Comment: Rather than using reflection, would it make sense for your setters to convert empty string to null?

Comment: can using dozer mapping a solution ?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against such a generic approach, as it breaks encapsulation. 1) Imagine a colleage debugging some strange behaviour "I'm sure I've set `name` to an empty String, and I've seen it happen. Why is it `null` now? Who is magically changing private field values?" If it's done via reflection, he'll have a very hard time finding the place responsible for the change. 2) You can't be sure *now* that *all* String fields (including *future ones*) will ask for that null-instead-of-empty-string behaviour.